# Couchbase PHP SDK in Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, couchbase

I have a Docker container that runs PHP-FPM 5.5 and I'd like to ensure that it has access to the Couchbase SDK. I have this working outside of Docker and can't really picture how Docker would interfere and yet I seem to be running into a problem that is "probably" docker related:

My Docker container runs under **Ubuntu 14.04** and includes the following installation (after installing PHP):

```
# Install Couchbase C-library and PECL extension
RUN wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase-ubuntu1404.list \
        && wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add - \
        && apt-get update \
        && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends pkg-config libcouchbase2-libevent libcouchbase-dev libmemcached-dev php-pear php5-dev make \
        && pecl config-set php_ini /app/conf/php.ini \
        && pecl install couchbase --alldeps \
        && pecl install memcached --alldeps \
        && { \
            echo "; Couchbase PHP SDK"; \
            echo "extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/couchbase.so"; \
        } > /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/30-couchbase.ini \
        && cp /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/30-couchbase.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d \
        && { \
            echo "; Memcached PHP SDK"; \
            echo "extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/memcached.so"; \
        } > /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/30-memcached.ini \
        && cp /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/30-memcached.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
```

This SHOULD install both the C-libraries and the PECL extensions for **Couchbase** and **Memcached** support. In many ways it DOES appear to:

- `php -m` does include these modules as installed,
- and `phpinfo()` reports on their configuration as such:

[image: couchbase]

[image: memcached]

However, whenever I try to instantiate either a `Couchbase` or `Memcached` class can't find the class. So if I run the following program:

```
<?php
    $foo = new Couchbase();
    $bar = new Memcached();
    print_r($foo);
    print_r($bar);
?>
```

it gives me the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Couchbase' not found in /app/test.php on line 2

---

**UPDATE**: It turns out, however, that while Couchbase *does not* work, Memcached does. Not sure if that helps or hurts the troubleshooting but Couchbase seems to be the exclusive pain point.

Comment: Anyone wanting to try this in Docker can find the image at **lifegadget/docker-php:5.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, it appears, has to do with Couchbase moving from their 1.x to 2.x SDK's which in the case of PHP means that there is no longer a class called "Couchbase".

The longer term answer will be to migrate to this new API; which does look like it will require some work. In the near term, however, I needed a solution that would work for my existing use of Couchbase and that is quite simple ... just install the right version of Couchbase:

```
 pecl install couchbase-1.2.2
```

That's all that was needed for me. You can see a working Docker of this setup at: [lifegadget/docker-php](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/lifegadget/docker-php/)

> Note: the default version of the SDK you get from PECL is now 2.0 so if you're not specifying a version you're getting version 2.x.